# Host unreacheable from laptop but reacheable from desktop

Tags: ssh, networking, icmp, synology

I have a Synology NAS at home (let's call it ananas), it is attached to my router via ethernet.
I also have a desktop (let's call it Aero), it is connected to the same router via wifi.
I configured in another country, a laptop (xps13), I could access the NAS without any problem (the ports were open and I used NAT) using https rsync over ssh and ssh.

Here is a map of the local network:
[image: network map]

However now that I am back home, I just can't find the NAS by using nmap (without `-Pn`, it is just not listed while everything else is), can't ping it, and can't ssh into it. The twist is that this only happens on the laptop.

Running `route -n` on the xps 13 yields:

```
[soulthym@xps13 ~]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

And on the Aero:

```
[soulthym@Aero ~]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

For debugging purposes I disabled the firewall on the NAS, disabled IP auto-blocking on the NAS, and set the exact same firewall on both the Desktop and the Laptop (using /etc/iptables/iptables.rules).

From the xps13 I get:

```
[soulthym@xps13 ~]$ nmap -Pn 192.168.1.17
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-08-19 18:22 CEST
Nmap scan report for ananas-1.home (192.168.1.17)
Host is up (0.16s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on ananas-1.home (192.168.1.17) are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.88 seconds
```

Whereas I get all the ports from the Aero.

Same story goes for pinging, works beautifully from the Aero, but the xps13 yields:

```
[soulthym@xps13 ~]$ ping 192.168.1.17
PING 192.168.1.17 (192.168.1.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.13 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.13 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.13 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

And while ssh-ing:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.17 port $PORT: No route to host
```

```
[soulthym@xps13 ~]$ ip neigh 
192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx REACHABLE 
192.168.1.10 dev wlp2s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx STALE 
192.168.1.17 dev wlp2s0 FAILED xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx 
             dev wlp2s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx router REACHABLE
```

(the above fragment was moved from a comment, and was broken there)

This only happens when using the local network. I can use a VPN and connect to the public IP but that is just a temporary fix that doesn't fit the use for backups...

Any idea of what I could have done wrong here?

Comment: Your `nmap` output for xps13 indicates that it knows the host is up, but ports are filtered by a firewall. Is it possible that there is a filter on your NAT that's blocking xps13?

Comment: @Peschke not that I know of, and it would mean it only blocks this specific ip? Because it works when using a VPN or ssh-ing from the public IP

Comment: I'm not sure. I reread the `nmap` man page for `-Pn`, which says it treats all hosts as online. Therefore, I think my observation about xps13 seeing your NAT as up is incorrect. Can xps13 access or ping Aero while connected to your local network?

Comment: No in fact it can not, and while scanning without -Pn it did not find the NAS. I'll edit and add this information to the post

Comment: If Aero's iptables allows pings, is your router not allowing xps13 to communicate on the internal network? Maybe check the router settings. I'm out of other ideas at the moment.

Comment: @Peschke I'll check that but there is no reason whatsoever

Comment: I suspect a lower layer problem. What does `ip neigh? say on xps13 after `ping 192.168.1.17`?

Comment: @JohanMyréen 
```
[soulthym@xps13 ~]$ ip neigh 
192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx REACHABLE
192.168.1.10 dev wlp2s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx STALE
192.168.1.17 dev wlp2s0  FAILED
xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev wlp2s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx router REACHABLE
```
(replaced the mac + ipv6 with x)

Comment: You'll get the same result for any non-existent IP address on the `192.168.1.0/24` network. The laptop cannot see the NAS on the link link layer (L2) , possibly because of wrongly configured WiFi.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't see how it can happen given that the WiFi is using the default settings. I only customized the NAT and a default IP on the DHCP settings for some machines. I'll look more into it though as I don't see anything else

Comment: I went through every setting possible on the box, no luck whatsoever @Johan Myréen

Comment: All the signs are telling me the xps13 can't get the MAC address of the NAS using ARP. Which hints that the NAS can't be reached over Wi-fi at all. Can the desktop machine communicate with the NAS (using Wi-Fi)?

Comment: @JohanMyréen it can in fact communicate with it.

Comment: Edit to tell us if the desktop and laptop are connected the same way (wifi, cable, etc). Also repeat tests for desktop and show results.

Comment: I added your last comment to the question, but there is some missing (where did it go?).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a DNS entry in the router's DNS itself allows to bypass the issue.
As of now, I can not access the NAS by IP but at least I can by "nickname".

Comment: What is in the DNS record?